# Cosa significa “si diceva nei libri” in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Ho letto nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante:

> Cosa ho fatto, pensò stordita dal vino, e cos'è questo cerchietto d'oro, questo zero luccicante dentro cui ho infilato il dito. Ne aveva uno anche Stefano, gli brillava tra peli nerissimi, dita villose, **si diceva nei libri**.

Forse si può sostituire quell'espressione con "come nei libri"? Sapreste aiutarmi ad intendere il significato giusto?

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No non è sostituibile con "come nei libri", piuttosto con "come si usa dire nei libri".
Per come la intendo io, semplicemente la protagonista considera *dita villose* un'espressione cólta (che si usa nei libri).

Comment: Grazie per l'aiuto! Mi pare che sarebbe stato più chiaro e consueto se fosse stato scritto "come si diceva nei libri".